# Is there a way to find the data points in a K-means Cluster from SciKit-Learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I have a data set that contains comments from bird watchers. I used TF-IDF vectorizer to convert the text comments into vector features, and then ran K-means clustering to separate my data into clusters. I have a set of clear clusters. However, I have been trying to find a way to find out which words made it into which clusters. I am aware of how to get the feature labels/names, but I want to see the actual data points under each feature, and then convert them back to the original words. I am using Python and Scikit-Learn's K-means algorithm.

```
def final_k_model(X, finalk):
    final_k_mod = KMeans(n_clusters=finalk, init='random', n_init=10, max_iter=300, tol=1e-04, random_state=0)
    final_k_mod.fit(X)

    # plot the results:
    centroids = final_k_mod.cluster_centers_

    tsne_init = 'pca'
    tsne_perplexity = 20.0
    tsne_early_exaggeration = 4.0
    tsne_learning_rate = 1000
    random_state = 1
    tsnemodel = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=random_state, init=tsne_init, perplexity=tsne_perplexity,
                 early_exaggeration=tsne_early_exaggeration, learning_rate=tsne_learning_rate)

    transformed_centroids = tsnemodel.fit_transform(centroids)

    plt.figure(1)
    plt.scatter(transformed_centroids[:, 0], transformed_centroids[:, 1], marker='x')
    plt.savefig('plots\\cluster.png')
    plt.show()

    return final_k_mod
```

I included some code, but not sure if it helps as I don't have an error. I am just trying to figure out if this is even possible, I've been googling and looking at tutorials but haven't found it.

Comment: For the next time, please spend a minute to see how to format your code (done it for you this time).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you calculated the X in your code by the following method,

```
#corpus = list of all documents
#vocab = list of all words in corpus
tdf_idf = TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary=vocab)
X = tdf_idf.fit_transform(corpus)
```

is the following that you are looking for?

```
for centroid in centroids:
    score_this_centroid = {}
    for word in tdf_idf.vocabulary_.keys():
        score_this_centroid[word] = centroid[tdf_idf.vocabulary_[word]]
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped! I tried to vote up your answer but I think I am too new.  :(